# HTML5 middle align in table data

Tags: css, html

I have a big table and this is the last row of that table:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
      <button type="submit" id="backButton">Back</button>
    </form> 

    <form action="deleteServlet" method="post">
      <button type="submit" name="delete" class="deleteButton"
        value="${placeholder.placeholder_id}">Delete</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Inside my last td there are two buttons inside forms (is this good way to do it?). What I want to do is to middle align both "Back" and "Delete" buttons so that they look nice. Now it looks like a zigzag (see picture). I've given id or class -tags to those buttons and tried to move them with bottom, left, display, float etc. commands with no results.

I can't make two td's (one td for one button) because there is so much space between td's.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I think forms are block level elements, have you tried setting them to be inline-block

Comment: Have you tried `<td valign="middle">`?

Comment: Klors should add that as answer, see http://jsfiddle.net/5P9NE/ that it should be enough(inline would work as well)

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/Lrp4A/

Comment: @Drewness it's usually a bad practice to put inline style. Better to do that on the stylesheet.

Comment: @Eagle - Agreed. It's also bad practice to use tables. :/

Comment: @Drewness usually yes, tables are bad practice when used for layout. Table for tabular data is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5D8g/) to demonstrate. [/edit]

Forms are block-level elements, simply turn them into `inline-block` and they'll sit nicely side-by-side.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="index.jsp" method="get" style="display: inline-block;">
                <button type="submit" id="backButton">Back</button>
            </form>
            <form action="deleteServlet" method="post" style="display: inline-block;">
                <button type="submit" name="delete" class="deleteButton" value="${placeholder.placeholder_id}">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The styling would be better done as part of your stylesheet, but added here as style attributes for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks! Extra Q: How can I add spacing between those buttons? I just can't add margin to my form in CSS, because it will affect to all my forms obv.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to give the forms a class attribute to make them easier to style, eg. `class="inlineform"` and then style them based upon the class so that it doesn't affect all of your forms, eg. `form.inlineform { margin: ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td style="line-height:30px;">
    <div style="height:30px; float:left;">
      <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
        <button type="submit" id="backButton">Back</button>
      </form> 
    </div>
    <div style="height:30px; float:left;">
      <form action="deleteServlet" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="delete" class="deleteButton"
          value="${placeholder.placeholder_id}">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Let me know if it works (or not) :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply align form tag with `display:inline-block` in last-child `td`

Clarification in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/uHCyU/